# malloc in child thread cost too much virtual memory

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, glibc

```
void * thread_client_timeout_check(void *arg)
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;size_t size;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_getstacksize(&attr, &size);
    printf("pthread stacksize: %d\n", size);
    malloc(1);
}
```

main thread create the child and pause.

```
int main()
{
    pthread_t pid;
    pthread_create(&pid, NULL, thread_client_timeout_check, NULL);
    pause();
}
```

1. before `pthread_create`, `top virt` is `0.3m`
2. after `pthread_create`, `top virt`is`8.3m` (pthread stack size is 8m)
3. after `malloc(1)`,`top virt`is`72.3m`

Why `malloc(1)` will get `54m` virtual memory from kernel?

Comment: And no other threads does anything else that might increase memory?

Comment: If malloc went all the way down to the kernel for each and every allocation, it would be pretty slow. Getting large chunks and then dealing with them all in userspace makes much more sense.

Comment: @ Mat You are right, but 54m is too large. And i check `malloc(1)` in main thread first, virtual memory is still 0.3m.

Comment: How you get `virt`? With `top` `VIRT` field?

Comment: Virtual address space does indeed increase (64 megabyte in each thread when I tried it now), but why not? Linux doesn't (necessarily) reserve any physical memory until it is actually used, and perhaps the implementors of malloc decided that allocating a large chunk of virtual memory addresses for each thread was good for performance.

Comment: @TrueY  Yes, `top` or `cat /proc/<pid>/status`

Comment: @Thomas I am working in embedded Linux. Large virtual memory  scared me. I used to check virtual memory for memory leak.

Comment: @jianxisun: I won't promise you that your kernel will not behave differently, but I changed your **malloc(1)** to **malloc(10L*1024*1024*1024)** (10 gigabytes) and did this in ten simultaneous threads, allocating a total of 100 gigabytes of virtual memory, with no ill effects whatsoever when I tried it just now.

Comment: Yes, virtual memory is just address space. Practically free, particularly on 64-bit architectures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a multithreaded program, glibc 2.10+ creates a number of malloc pools in order to reduce false sharing and thus improve scalability. The result is that as of glibc 2.10, the virtual memory usage will be much higher. But as address space is cheap, or more or less free on 64-bit architectures, it's really nothing to worry about.

See https://udrepper.livejournal.com/20948.html

Answer (score 2):

Virtual memory (`virt`) is not the memory allocated by the program. Rather similar to a kind memory foot print (contains data + code + resident + swapped memory. Also it contains shared code and data segments used by shared libraries). **Glibc's** `malloc` memory allocation uses different strategies for different block sizes (fastbins, mmap(), sbrk()) and small actual memory usage can cause huge virt memory. E.g. allocate 10 times 64 KiB + 1KiB blocks and free the lower 10 x 64KiB blocks. The actual usage 1 KiB, but the memory on the heap counted in virt is 641 KiB (+cca 100 KiB for the topmost (so called wilderness) chunk) as the freed memory on the heap still belongs the process's address space.

You can see the actual free memory using the `mallinfo(3)`:

```
#include <malloc.h>

#define pfld(fld, unit, rem) printf("  %-9s= %d %s, (%s)\n", #fld, mi.fld, #unit, rem)

void showmem(const char *fnc, const char *step) {
    struct mallinfo mi = mallinfo();

    printf("\n==== %s: %s ====\n", fnc, step);

    pfld(arena,    bytes, "Non-mmapped space allocated");
    pfld(ordblks,  pcs,   "free chunks");
    pfld(smblks,   pcs,   "free fastbin blocks");
    pfld(hblks,    pcs,   "mmapped regions");
    pfld(hblkhd,   bytes, "Space allocated in mmapped regions");
    pfld(usmblks,  bytes, "Maximum total allocated space");
    pfld(fsmblks,  bytes, "Space in freed fastbin blocks");
    pfld(uordblks, bytes, "Total allocated space");
    pfld(fordblks, bytes, "Total free space");
    pfld(keepcost, bytes, "Top-most, releasable space");
}
```

Calling this function from different part of your program as `showmem(__FUNCTION__, "Step")` you can see the total allocated space and the total free space. I assume that in your case the total free space is high and the total allocated space is low. And this can be because of the memory allocated and freed by the pthread library.

You can make a test. Using `mallopt(3)` you can ask the malloc to always use `mmap(2)` to allocate memory not the more convenient `sbrk(2)`. Usually `mmap(2)` is used only for blocks larger then or equal to 128 KiB. Mmap'd memory is always zeroed when malloc'd (causing processing overhead and always allocates 4KiB pages) as provided by kernel and after free always removed from the process's address space and given back to kernel (so reading from the free'd pointer will cause a segmentation fault). If an mmap'd memory is freed it is immediately removed from your address space, so the allocated memory foot-print will be reduced immediately. Try: malloc 10 x 128 KiB + 1 KiB, then free the 10 x 128 KiB. Virt will be reduced to contain only the 1 KiB part.

Calling

```
mallopt(M_MMAP_THRESHOLD, 0);
```

at the beginning of your program will force **glibc**'s malloc to always use `mmap(3)`. If my assumption is true then the virt mem will be reduced. I do not recommend to use this (for small chunks it cause large memory overhead and always fill up memory page with 0 causing CPU overhead), but the theory can be tested.

This is just with **glibc**. Other memory managers (like tcmalloc) uses different strategies.

I hope this helps!